# Confusing duplicate target for Java Boolean default value

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I was looking to check what is the default value for a boolean in Java. This was asked several times:

- *[Default value of boolean and Boolean in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226290/default-value-of-boolean-in-java)*
- *[Default Boolean value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509150/default-boolean-value-in-java)*

Both of those are closed as a duplicate of:

*[Why is Java's default value for Boolean set to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048313/why-is-javas-default-value-for-boolean-set-to-true)*

The second one shows two duplicate targets, one of them being the first question.

The choice of the duplicate target doesn't seem good to me. The question is confusing, it starts with some assumption which is not true, and it does not show the specific code.

The questions asks:

> Why does `private Boolean shouldDropTables`; assign `true` by default to the variable instead of `NULL`

... which it does not, unless there is some more code. The OP even does not tell why he/she thinks the value is `true`. Perhaps he has seen it in the debugger. Perhaps it has failed a test `shouldDropTables == false` ... how can one guess?

When seeing this, I would immediately close it as "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") ..."

I think a question simple and basic like this (default Boolean value in Java) would deserve a good canonical answer.

How can this be fixed? I could vote to close the current duplicate target and to reopen the questions linking to it, once reopened the vote to close one of them as a dupe of the other, but I am not sure if this is a right way to proceed.

Comment: I've voted to reopen the first one. It has 315k views while the target has 15k views. It clearly has a better title/wording for a canonical question.

Answer (score 19):

Since I hold a gold badge in Java, I changed the dupes around (and edited the "canonical").

Since the canonical answers both questions sufficiently, I simply closed the other as a dupe of it and removed the multiple entries on the dupe list so that it reads less confusingly.

Comment: I edited the canonical so it asks about `boolean` in addition to `Boolean`. There were only 2 answers which did not already mention the default value of `boolean`. (One of the answers even gave the default value of `boolean` instead of `Boolean`.) Anyway, it's more unified now.

Comment: @Radiodef:  It *really* didn't need that...

Comment: There are some people complaining in [the comments for this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21509150/default-boolean-value-in-java) that the duplicate is "only about `Boolean`", despite answering for both.

Comment: The comments could be wiped clean by a moderator since they're serving as noise now.

Comment: should https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048313/why-is-javas-default-value-for-boolean-set-to-true actually be closed as "cannot reproduce" instead of duplicate. There's no way for any of us to reproduce that the way OP has it, since there is no information. Don't really understand 36 upvotes on it...

Comment: TIL some languages made a new word called lowercase `boolean`... great... there should be only one Boolean, the capitalized one...

Answer (score 3):

An incorrect assumption can still be a good question.

That dupe target certainly isn't a *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") ..."*. It has 2 similar but different code snippets that have 2 different outcomes that the OP would like to have explained. That seems perfectly valid to me.

Either way,

Gold badge owners can *edit* the "duplicate of" list of a question. If a dupe target needs to be changed, editing it is quite a lot easier than re-opening and closing.

Comment: What I find confusing is none of the snippets included in the questions shows behaviour OP is asking about, namely Boolean set to true.

Comment: If gold hammer owners can do it, what would be the proper way to notify them considering it? Raising this meta topic, commenting on the question, or something else?

Comment: The easiest way would be to poke someone on chat, but that's not always appreciated. You could comment mentioning the better dupe target, and if a user with a gold hammer sees it, they could edit the list.

Comment: `That dupe target certainly isn't a Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") ...` Why do you think it isn't? He is asking why something is the way it is, which its not... For it to be that we would need more context.... The answers are great but the question itself is bad

Comment: @EpicKip: it’s asking for an explanation about how the language works. It’s not debugging an application.

Comment: @Cerbrus But its asking why something works like it does, he may think its the language but its his code. Does it matter if the asker knows if he's actually debugging his code?

Comment: @EpicKip: I'm just saying I don't think that it's a valid close reason here.

Comment: @Cerbrus I understand, I was just asking to get your input ^^